# Quick way to calculate uniformity or discrepancy of number set

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, uniform

Hello
Assume I have the set of numbers I want a quick to calculate some measure of uniformity.
I know the variance is the most obvious answer but i am afraid the complexity of naive algorithm is too high
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any programming language constraint ?

Comment: Why do you think the standard (sum squares) algorithm is too complex?

Comment: I program in c++ but I really like to see the general algorithm

Comment: For some pseudo-codes look here --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Intuitive" algorithms for calculating variance usually suffer one or both of the following:

1. Use two loops (one for calculating the mean, the other for the variance)
2. Are not [numerically stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability)

A good algorithm, with only one loop and numerically stable is due to [D. Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/) (as always).

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance):

```
n = 0
mean = 0
M2 = 0
 def calculate_online_variance(x):
    n = n + 1
    delta = x - mean
    mean = mean + delta/n
    M2 = M2 + delta*(x - mean)  # This expression uses the new value of mean

    variance_n = M2/n
    variance = M2/(n - 1) #note on the first pass with n=1 this will fail (should return Inf)
    return variance
```

You should invoke calculate_online_variance(x) for each point, and it returns the variance calculated so far.

Comment: you mentioned lack of numerical stability, examples?  I'm just not seeing it where it would creep in using `mean(x)^2 - mean(x^2)`.  I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: @rcollyer I was refering to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Two-pass_algorithm

Comment: well it seems I need to actually read the links posted in the answers ... either way, gracias and +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Better this way ... I can't stand an argument about numerical stability with you :)

Comment: Numerical stability is a problem in this common case:  if `mean^2` >> `variance`, you are subtracting two large numbers to get a small one, which kills your floating point precision.